# Chef Recipes, not_if

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

bash "edit gemfile" do

```
cwd "/home/vagrant/myapp"
code <<-EOH
echo "group :development, :test do
gem 'capybara'
gem 'rspec-rails'
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
gem 'capybara-screenshot'
gem 'launchy'
end" >>Gemfile
EOH
#####not_if do ::File.exists?('/home/vagrant/myapp/Gemfile') end#####
end
```

I want it to not add it again on Gemfile once it is added already to avoid duplicate...
please tell me how to use the proper not_if command, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This `not_if { ::File.exists?('/home/vagrant/myapp/Gemfile') }` should do.

Here you're using the block syntax do .. end on one line, in this case you have to end your commands inside the block with a semicolon ;

For your syntax it will be `not_if do ::File.exists?('/home/vagrant/myapp/Gemfile'); end`

If you omit the semicolon, the interpreter can't guess if your passing `end` as an argument or a keyword.

rule of thumb: use curly braces `{}` for one liner and `do .. end` for multiline blocks.

Comment: yes but, what I mean is that if the said commands are already inside the Gemfile, then I don't want it to execute anymore.
the not_if code above is you wont run the command if there is a Gemfile found right?

Comment: Right. Usually it is a bad idea to manage only part of a file with chef. You should better use a template to manage the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

Your not_if needs to use `grep` or `awk` or a ruby block to inspect the gemfile and see if it contains the lines you want.

Comment: How to do that? please tell me. @Tejay Cardon

Comment: @JustineGumba Is there any chance that some, but not all, of those GEMs will be in the Gemfile already?  If there is, things get much more tricky, but still pretty straight forward.